# How to duplicate an artboard without the layers getting shuffled on illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers

i want to make replicas of a complex illustration to play with color schemes but when I duplicate the artboard all the layers get jacked up. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of duplicating the artboard, you could create a new layer, then copy and paste the artwork onto a new artboard, thus keeping the duplicated objects on a layer of their own. Doing it that way will ensure the original artboard's layer structure is not touched.

See this example:

[image]
Click image for larger size

Answer (score 0):

- **Copy the layer(s) first.**
- **Lock** the original layer(s).
- *Then* create a new artboard and move the new layer you created.

The *unlocked* layer(s) will move when copying an artboard (if that option is checked) while the *locked* layer(s) will remain on the original artboard. Only *unlocked* layers will move with any artboard.

Answer (score 0):

As @Scott says, just lock the layers first.  Then go to the Artboard tool, click the artboard you want to copy, then alt-drag that artboard to copy it like any other object.